# Rewrite nginx path when using proxy

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having some difficulties trying to rewrite a path on a site we are proxying using nginx.  I'm looking to trim part of the url and hit the new page.

Here's the urls trying to change:
from

```
https://subdomain.maindomain.com/page/v1/mycontent
```

to (301 status code)

```
https://subdomain.maindomain.com/page/mycontent
```

So just trimming the v1 part.  Here's the location block that I'm using:

```
    location /page/v1 {
        rewrite ^/v1(/.*)$ $1 break;

        proxy_pass http://myproxy;
        proxy_set_header host subdomain.maindomain.com;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

The proxy side is working fine and not too concerned by that.  The bit I'm struggling with is the change in th path.

Anyone any ideas as drawing a blank.  There's a few similar questions on Stack Overflow but not managed to get a working solution just yet?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the `/page` part of the URI. Try: `rewrite ^(.*)/v1(/.*)$ $1$2 break;`

Comment: No joy with that either, thanks